# Create element representing position of XML elements keyed by 2 different keys

Tags: xslt

Given the following XML document:

```
<doc>
  <foo>
    <key1>1</key1>
    <key2>1</key2>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <key1>1</key1>
    <key2>1</key2>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <key1>1</key1>
    <key2>2</key2>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <key1>1</key1>
    <key2>2</key2>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <key1>1</key1>
    <key2>2</key2>
  </foo>
</doc>
```

I need to add to each group of foo elements keyed by (key1, key2) the position number in the group like this:

```
<doc>
  <foo>
    <key1>1</key1>
    <key2>1</key2>
    <pos>1</pos>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <key1>1</key1>
    <key2>1</key2>
    <pos>2</pos>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <key1>1</key1>
    <key2>2</key2>
    <pos>1</pos>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <key1>1</key1>
    <key2>2</key2>
    <pos>2</pos>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <key1>1</key1>
    <key2>2</key2>
    <pos>3</pos>
  </foo>
</doc>
```

I tried to create a key `<xsl:key match="foo" use="concat(key1, '|', key2)" name="group"/>` which should me allow to group the `foo` elements by their key values, but I'm at a loss on how to write the corresponding template which will create the `pos` element.

The template likely will look something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="foo[???]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:element name="pos">
    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But what to put for the '???'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <pos>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('group', concat(key1, '|', key2))">
                <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($this)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </pos>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

A complete stylesheet is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key match="foo" use="concat(key1, '|', key2)" name="group"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <pos>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('group', concat(key1, '|', key2))">
                    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($this)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </pos>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 2.0 (and the help of the [`functx` function library](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_index-of-node.html)) the code is more compact:

```
<xsl:import href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xsl"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key match="foo" use="concat(key1, '|', key2)" name="group"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <pos>
            <xsl:value-of select="functx:index-of-node(key('group', concat(key1, '|', key2)), current())"/>
        </pos>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. But it is significantly more complicated than what I'd have expected. I sorely miss the simplicity of SQL statements.

Comment: Let me try to understand... `key('group', concat(key1, '|', key2))`returns all nodes that have the same key as the current node. I.e. for k=(1,2) it returns the third and forth `foo` element. The inner loop then picks the element from the list whose ID matches the currently matched outer `foo` element and inserts its position number. Is that more or less correct?

Comment: Yes, `key('group', concat(key1, '|', key2))` gives us all the items in a group defined by the key, now we need to establish the position of the currently matched `foo` item in that group and to do that we need to process the group with the `for-each` and compare the identity, which is done in XSLT 1.0 with the `generate-id()` comparison (in XSLT 2.0 we could simply do `<xsl:if test=". is $this">`).  I will add an XSLT 2.0 sample where the expression (with the help of a library function) is more compact and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this Muenchian grouping  version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="k1k2" match="foo" use="concat(key1, '|', key2)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/doc">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each
                select="foo[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1k2', concat(key1, '|', key2))[1])]" >
                <!-- group -->
                <xsl:for-each
                    select="key('k1k2', concat(key1, '|', key2))" >
                    <!-- group member-->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."  >
                        <xsl:with-param name="group-pos" select="position()" />
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo">
        <xsl:param name="group-pos" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"  />
            <pos>
                <xsl:value-of select="$group-pos"/>
            </pos>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but has the unfortunate side effect that it reorders the `foo` elements in the document, which I'd rather avoid.